# generate different password for each usr in list

Tags: bash, passwords

I use the following bash script to change password for users in list:

```
pass=`cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9-_!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?=' | fold -w 12 | grep -i '[!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?=]' | head -n 1`
for usr in `cat usrs.lst`
do
printf "Username is $usr and password is $pass\n"
done
```

The problem with the previous code it that doesn't change the password
meaning it gives one password for every user.
I need the previous script to give a different password for each user
so what am I missing in the previous code?

Comment: thanks all the problem get solved by including pass variable inside for loop

Answer (score 1):

you should assign pass variable in loop as below;

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r usr; do
  pass=$(tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9-!@#$%^&*()+{}|:<>?=' < /dev/urandom | fold -w 12 | grep -i '[!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?=]' | head -n 1)
  printf 'Username is %s and password is %s\n' "$usr" "$pass"
done < usrs.lst
```

Comment: thanks all the problem get solved by including pass variable inside for loop

Comment: There are couple of really bad `bash` practices in your syntax.1)  Looping over the file using `cat`, rather than using while-loop syntax `while IFS= read ..; do ; done <file` 2) Incorrect usage of command substitution, without `$(..)`